Is there a way to get a list of files that are present in Infrequent Access (IA) in AWS EFS file system?
I want to delete the files in IA out of all the files present in my EFS file system. However, the problem is that I don't know precisely which are the files present in IA in my EFS file system. Is there a way to know that?

There is no direct way in the console or the api of EFS to list files, So you need a solution for that.
So if yu just need to list all files in EFS, maybe you just try to connect to an EC2 where the EFS is mounted (that suppose it's mounted at root level of the EFS), then you list with some linux commands (ls, tree, find...).
But if you need to visulaize EFS without an EC2 you can choose to use Simple File Manager for Amazon EFS with a minimal cost but with a web browsing interface.

What file operations are considered as access ? Is there not a risk of "reactivating" the files by doing a file operation (for example find . -atime +30) ? Can one use an  application such as agedu https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/agedu/ without bringing back all the files into Standard Storage ?

The docs state : "File metadata, including file names, ownership information, and file system directory structure, is always stored in Standard to help ensure consistent metadata performance.
Metadata operations for file systems in IA or Archive storage, such as listing the contents of a directory, don't count as file access. During the process of transitioning a file's content to the IA or Archive storage classes, the file is stored in the Standard storage class and is billed at that storage rate."

link : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/lifecycle-management-efs.html

For the GUI app I would use the one provided by AWS

I would suggest using agedu https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/agedu/ to assess the space used according to the age of the files.
